# How to write an async function with a generic type without using const

Tags: typescript, function, constants, typescript-generics, signature

Is it possible to write this code without using `export const`, but rather `export async function`?

This is a sample of the code, heavily simplified:

```ts
interface Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

type Listener<Subject, Payload extends object> = (event: {
  subject: Subject;
  payload?: Partial<Payload>;
}) => Promise<void>;

export const onEvent: Listener<Product, never> = async (event) => {
  await new Promise(function (resolve) {
    
    // a simplified example of using the parameters
    console.log(event.subject.id, event.subject.name);

    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  });
};
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to write this in the form of

`export async function onEvent ... {`

Without breaking it down into, for example

`export async function onEvent(event: { subject: Product; payload?: never }): Promise<void> {`

It doesn't seem like it after reading the current Typescript docs.

Comment: Is `Listener` part of your codebase or is it imported from a library?

Comment: It's a part of the codebase - not imported :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no there isn't. With the 'function' keyword, the type is derived from the arguments and return type, you can't separately specify the type. You could do

```
export const onEvent: Listener<Product, never> = async function (event) {...}
```

but that's about it.